# How to make a fire in the wild, without burning the ground?

Tags: diy

I was wondering if there was a way to make a fire pit and start a fire in it, and have a way to protect the ground beneith it as much as possible.

I don't really know how I could manage to do that, but whatever item you'd advice me to use, it has to be lightweight, and not too big, something I could have in my backpack.

Maybe there's absolutely no way to do it, but I was just wondering. I hate destroying the floor when I make a campfire.

Thank you !

Comment: This is an exact duplicate; use the pre-existing question for answers!